# How do I set up DNS to respond to one or two hosts in a domain with my entries and forward the rest?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns

I'm not that familiar with DNS, I have a DNS server that handles all of our internal DNS entries and its fine.  However we have a software package now that points to a host that exists "publicly" however we are supposed to use a different IP to access this server.  I can put an entry in the local machine's host file and the software works but this is going on a lot of systems and I don't want outdated host files everywhere.

If I make a new zone on our DNS to handle this domain i can get the software to work by putting in a record, but then all of the other hosts on that domain break since I don't have records for them.  (For instance, the www entry doesn't exist so going to the public website results in not finding a host).

So I'd like to put in one or two entries in our DNS for a zone I have no control/authority on and have it serve those internally but forward everything else out.

Comment: What DNS server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

what you could do is the following. Setup a dns server running on 127.0.0.1:5353 resolving the entries you want. In front of that you use a dns cache f.e. dnsmasq. in dnsmasq you could do:

```
server=/domain.tld/203.0.113.1
server=/host1.domain.tld/127.0.0.1#5353
server=/host2.domain.tld/127.0.0.1#5353
```

this should direct queries for host1 and host2 to the local instance and all other queries for the same domain to 203.0.113.1 (which represents your providers dns resolver) and all other queries will be forwarded to the servers configured in /etc/resolv.conf.

hth

Answer (score 0):

You can add a zone for the FQDN (e.g host1.donain.tld) so queries for anything other than *.host1.domain.tld will go to the original authoritative DNS server. It's not perfect, but it'll work.